# R/Shiny update input control immediately

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny UI which launches some long-running server code. I want to update the input controls with some calculated defaults on page load and have this displayed and used immediately (the long-running code triggers on page load or submit button). The start of my server looks like this:

```
shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session) {
    observe({
      startDate <- weekdaysBefore(Sys.Date(), 5)
      endDate <- weekdaysBefore(Sys.Date(), 1)
      updateDateInput(session, 'startDate', value = startDate)
      updateDateInput(session, 'endDate', value = endDate)
    })

    # long-running calculations
```

However, the controls only update after everything else runs. This means the UI displays the initial values of the controls instead of the calculated values above whilst the code is running, the server code runs with the initial values, then when the results are presented the controls update to show the desired values - but not the ones being displayed. The documentation for `updateDateInput` says:

> The input updater functions send a message to the client, telling it
>   to change the settings of an input object. The messages are collected
>   and sent after all the observers (including outputs) have finished
>   running.

I would like to update the controls without this collection and/or page load. How is this possible?

Comment: Apologies if I have missed read the above, but would it not be easier to have the input controls built using a dynamic function utilizing `shiny::tags`. As the documentation says the message is only sent until it has all finished. I only think this because I have a `shinyApp` that creates an input dropdown based on values returned from `MySQL`. I therefore created a function that produces the correct `HTML` regards of the number of items are returned.

Comment: I'd probably prefer to stay with "idiomatic" Shiny if possible but that is an option I did not know, thanks.

Comment: Fair enough, I do know when I was exploring dynamic dropdowns it was the only method. `tags` is part of `shiny` so isn't a "hacky" way of doing it.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I've got the same pb and right now i can only think about an ugly solution involving reactiveVal and eventObservers (that are either triggered by the input or by the update event). As it can often be needed it would be fine if shiny could offer some updaters that make a background reactive value, updating the input without waiting for the client and without having to make the code ugly

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize your UI with the appropriate values. The initial render will then be with the values you've selected.

```
ui <-dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(...),
  dashboardSidebar(
    dateRangeInput("dates",
                   "Date range",
                   start = as.character(Sys.Date()-4),
                   end = as.character(Sys.Date())),
  ),
  dashboardBody(
  .
  .
  .
  )
)
```

Comment: IIRC this will only update when the server is restarted.